# Order by Multiple Columns with SoQL

Tags: socrata

How do I format a query with multiple order by columns.  The data I'm working with has a date column and a time column and I want to order by both of them.  I know how to do this query in regular SQL but I can't make it work in SoQL.  Here is what I've tried:

This works ('date DESC') but isn't what I'm trying to do:

```
http://data.sfgov.org/resource/tmnf-yvry.json?$order=date+DESC
```

This fails ('date DESC, time DESC') with a 403 error:

```
http://data.sfgov.org/resource/tmnf-yvry.json?$order=date+DESC%2Ctime+ASC
```

This fails ("'date DESC, time DESC'") with a 403 error:

```
http://data.sfgov.org/resource/tmnf-yvry.json?$order=%27date+DESC%2C+time+DESC%27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, sorting on multiple columns at the same time is something you unfortunately can't do with the SODA API. It'll respond with a "query.execution.queryTooComplex" error like you're seeing.

However, this is something that'll be fixed in the future as we migrate datasets to our new backend. Details on this process and how to tell when/if a dataset has been migrated will be available soon.

Note: You also need to use the `$order` parameter in your query, not just `order`. I'll edit your URLs above to match.

Comment: Actually, it looks like adding three dollar signs (`$`) is too minor or Stack Overflow to accept. Hopefully you get the idea. :)

Comment: Oh, the $ are in the actual queries.  They got removed when I took out most of the rest of the query to make the question easier to read.  Thank you for the prompt answer.